# NSTextField new line operations

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I would like my NSTextField to add another line on enter (rather that option-enter). Is there any way to do that at all?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSTextField supports new line breaks by using Option-Return or Option-Enter. But under most circumstances the easiest solution would be to use NSTextView instead.

Answer (score 5):

Yep — by overriding `control` in a bound `NSTextFieldDelegate` you can intercept an enter keypress and make it do what you want.

Here's an example adapted from the article ["How to make NSTextField accept tab, return and enter keys."](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1454/_index.html) on Apple's developer portal:

```
(BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:))
    {
        // Insert a line-break character and don't cause the receiver
        // to end editing
        [textView insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Weirdly, that `NSTextView*` is not a typo, even though we're dealing with `NSTextField`s.

Comment: Text fields share a single text view as their field editor: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH8-BBCFEBHA

Comment: Also, you need to include all parameter labels as part of a method name – it’s not just `control`, it’s `control:textView:doCommandBySelector:`.